# send a complex object from SERVER1 to SERVER2

Tags: c#, json

I am trying so send not a single object, but a complex object from SERVER1 to SERVER2.

SERVER 1:

```
/// <summary>
/// SERVER 1
/// </summary>
internal void SomeActionMethod(Guid sid, CustomClass2 offer, List<CustomClass1> calculation)
{
    //The reason for wrapping this, is that "PostAsJsonAsync" will only except 1 dto, but I need both.
    List<Object> dto = new List<object>();
    dto.Add(offer);
    dto.Add(calculation);

    var resp = _client.PostAsJsonAsync(_baseadress + @"someController/SomeActionMethod?sid=" + sid.ToString(), dto).Result;

    if (!resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        throw new Exception(...);
}
```

SERVER 2:

```
/// <summary>
    /// SERVER 2 
    /// </summary>
    public void SomeActionMethod(Guid sid, [FromBody]List<object> dto)
    {
        //unwrapp
        CustomClass2 offer=new CustomClass2();
        List<CustomClass1> calculation=new List<CustomClass1>();

        foreach (var server1_item in dto)
        {
            if (server1_item is CustomClass2)
                offer = (CustomClass2)server1_item;
            else if (server1_item is List<CustomClass1>)
                calculation = (List<CustomClass1>)server1_item;
            else
                continue;
        }

        //Do some stuff
    }
```

I get some JSON, but not the thing I can check against `(server1_item is CustomClass2)`.

What to do here, how can I solve this problem ?!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By having it serialise and de-serialise to the `object` type you're essentially discarding all information which would tell the later code (on server2) anything about what type the data originally was.

Serialisation/Deserialisation to and from JSON is not the same as casting. It's the process of translating an object containing a series of properties from a code object to a string, and back again. It relies entirely on matching the property names in the type specified. In this case, `object` has no properties, so nothing is matched. You effectively discard everything in the JSON when you deserialise it, because the properties in the JSON don't match anything in the given type.

I think you may need to have two action methods on server2, one which takes `[FromBody]List<CustomClass1> dto` and another the same but for `CustomClass2`. Your client will have to decide which one to send to in different situations.

On the other hand, if you're trying to send a list containing a mix of the two types of object, then you could try deserialising to an Interface definition containing all the possible fields, or you could try using `dynamic` maybe. If you then need to cast to one of the two concrete classes afterwards though, you may have to do some manual checking of the populated properties to decide what type it is. This may point to a wider design issue in what you are trying to do, but that's not really something that's in the scope to deal with here.